# App script to export the Gsheets to CSV and replace the existing files in the same folder

Tags: csv, google-sheets, google-drive-api, export-csv

I am using the below app script to export Gsheets to CSV, however evertime i use the below code it created new folder/files on Gdrive however what i want to do is to update the exsisting CSV files on the same folder or a specific folder without creating new files/folders:

Used Code:

```
/*
 * script to export data in all sheets in the current spreadsheet as individual csv files
 * files will be named according to the name of the sheet
 * author: Michael Derazon
*/

function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var csvMenuEntries = [{name: "export as csv files", functionName: "saveAsCSV"}];
  ss.addMenu("csv", csvMenuEntries);
};

function saveAsCSV() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  // create a folder from the name of the spreadsheet
 var folder = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents().next();
  for (var i = 0 ; i < sheets.length ; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    // append ".csv" extension to the sheet name
    fileName = sheet.getName() + ".csv";
    // convert all available sheet data to csv format
    var csvFile = convertRangeToCsvFile_(fileName, sheet);
    // create a file in the Docs List with the given name and the csv data
    folder.createFile(fileName, csvFile);
  }
  Browser.msgBox('Files are waiting in a folder named ' + folder.getName());
}

function convertRangeToCsvFile_(csvFileName, sheet) {
  // get available data range in the spreadsheet
  var activeRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  try {
    var data = activeRange.getValues();
    var csvFile = undefined;

    // loop through the data in the range and build a string with the csv data
    if (data.length > 1) {
      var csv = "";
      for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
          if (data[row][col].toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
            data[row][col] = "\"" + data[row][col] + "\"";
          }
        }

        // join each row's columns
        // add a carriage return to end of each row, except for the last one
        if (row < data.length-1) {
          csv += data[row].join(",") + "\r\n";
        }
        else {
          csv += data[row];
        }
      }
      csvFile = csv;
    }
    return csvFile;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox(err);
  }
}
```

Expecting to update the exsisitng files everytime i push update not to create a new one unless a new sheet is added to the Gsheet

Comment: Have you tried adding an extra step: After getting the file name, search and delete the file with the same file name and then create the new/updated file with the file name?

Comment: Can you share a sample spreadsheet containing the sample format of the data used in this post?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to create a new file when the file of the same filename does not exist in `folder`.
- You want to update the file when the file of the same filename is existing in `folder`.

In this case, how about the following modification? In this modification, your function `convertRangeToCsvFile_` is used. And, please modify `saveAsCSV()` as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function saveAsCSV() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  // create a folder from the name of the spreadsheet
  var folder = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents().next();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    // append ".csv" extension to the sheet name
    fileName = sheet.getName() + ".csv";
    // convert all available sheet data to csv format
    var csvFile = convertRangeToCsvFile_(fileName, sheet);
    // create a file in the Docs List with the given name and the csv data

    // --- I modified the below script.
    var files = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);
    var file = files.hasNext() ? files.next() : folder.createFile(fileName, "", MimeType.CSV);
    file.setContent(csvFile);
    // ---

  }
  Browser.msgBox('Files are waiting in a folder named ' + folder.getName());
}
```

- By this modification, when the file of the same filename is existing in `folder`, the existing file is overwritten by a new value of `csvFile`. So, the file ID of the existing file is not changed.
- If you want to remove the existing file and create a new file by changing the file ID, please modify the above script as follows.

  - From

    ```js
    var files = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);
    var file = files.hasNext() ? files.next() : folder.createFile(fileName, "", MimeType.CSV);
    file.setContent(csvFile);
    ```
  - To

    ```js
    var files = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);
    if (files.hasNext()) {
      files.next().setTrashed(true);
    }
    folder.createFile(fileName, csvFile);
    ```

#### Note:

- I think that your goal can be also achieved using Drive API. But, from your showing script, I proposed the modification using Drive service (DriveApp) instead of Drive API.

#### Reference:

- [getFilesByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfilesbynamename)